# Downloading a file from AWS S3 in Xamarin iOS Hangs mostly

Tags: c#, file, amazon-s3, download, xamarin.ios

I am trying to download an XML file of size 85MB in my Xamarin iOS iPad App.
Sometimes download completes successfully, but other times download hangs inbetween somewhere without giving any error. Progress stops.

AWS SDK version:

AWSSDK.S3 3.3.20.4

AWSSDK.Core 3.3.24.8

I tried both methods 1- TransferUtility 2- GetObject.
Here is my code:

```
            var  clientRequest = new AmazonS3Client(AWSAccessKey,
                                    AWSSecretKey,
                                        Amazon.RegionEndpoint.USEast1);
            try
            {
                GetObjectRequest request = new GetObjectRequest
                {
                    BucketName = AWSBucketName,
                    Key = Path + "File1.xml"
                };
                using (GetObjectResponse response = await clientRequest.GetObjectAsync(request))
                {
                 response.WriteObjectProgressEvent += displayDownloadProgress;
                 await response.WriteResponseStreamToFileAsync(destPath, false);                        
                }
            }
            catch (AmazonS3Exception e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Error encountered ***. Message:'{0}' when writing an object", e.Message);
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Unknown encountered on server. Message:'{0}' when writing an object", e.Message);
            }
```

I tried both methods one by one.

```
            var utility = new TransferUtility(cas.AWSAccessKey,
                                    cas.AWSSecretKey,
                                    Amazon.RegionEndpoint.USEast1);

            TransferUtilityDownloadRequest dr = new TransferUtilityDownloadRequest();
            dr.BucketName = AWSBucketName;
            dr.Key = Path + "File1.xml";
            dr.FilePath = destPath;
            dr.WriteObjectProgressEvent += displayDownloadProgress;
            await utility.DownloadAsync(dr);



            public void displayDownloadProgress(object sender, WriteObjectProgressArgs args)
            {
                Debug.WriteLine("Download Progress: " + (args.PercentDone));

                InvokeOnMainThread(() =>
                {
                    BTProgressHUD.ShowContinuousProgress("Download Progress: " + args.PercentDone.ToString() + "%", ProgressHUD.MaskType.Gradient);
                });

                if (args.PercentDone >= 100)
                {
                    BTProgressHUD.Dismiss();
                }
            }
```

Comment: Here is a similar issue that you can refer https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/87305/run-download-method-with-aws-s3-in-xamarin-forms

Comment: @LucasZhang-MSFT Sorry, this is not the answer to my question. My Download functionality is working but hangs in between.